# Uncountable set has uncountably many limit points. (Proof Checking Request.)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> > Show that any uncountable subset of the reals has uncountably many limit points.

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb R$  be uncountable and let $L$ be the set of all the limit points of $S$.

Assume on the contrary that $L$ is at most countable.

Now.
For all $x\in S\setminus L$, there exist $a_x,b_x\in \mathbb Q$ be such that the open interval $U_x=(a_x,b_x)$ contains exactly one point of $S$.

Note that for all $x,y\in S\setminus L$, we have $x\neq y\iff U_x\neq U_y$.
Write $\mathcal C=\{U_x:x\in S\setminus L\}$.

Note that $\mathcal C$ is in bijection with $S\setminus L$.

But $\mathcal C$ can be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ and      hence $\mathcal C$ is countable.

This forces $S$ to be countable which contradicts the hypothesis.

Hence we achieve the required contradiction and the proof is complete.

Comment: Possible duplicate with [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17050/uncountably-many-points-of-an-uncountable-set-in-a-second-countable-are-limit-po) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233968/uncountable-limit-point-of-uncountable-set-munkres-topology)